# How to Drop database having space in between DBNAme

Tags: mysql

How to drop database having space in-between DB Name? In my case Database name is `Flight_Search DB_DEV`

[image]

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'db_dev' at line 1
>
> MYSQL Version is 8.0.33

Comment: use backticks around

Comment: [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) - study this at least now..

Answer (score 0):

Based [on this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23132) :

> If you want to use something around object identifiers, use at least
> the standard double quotes: "
>
> This works in MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc. etc. For
> MySQL you might need the SQL mode ansi_quotes, depending on the
> default configuration:
>
> SET sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES'; Backticks ` are only used in MySQL, you
> learn a type of SQL that won't work in any other brand of DBMS.

```
CREATE DATABASE `Flight_Search DB_DEV`;
```

```
DROP DATABASE `Flight_Search DB_DEV`;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VTa9L8cn)